# How to access outer object's attribute from an inner object?

Tags: javascript, object

Can the `outer`'s `value` be accessed from a function of the `inner` object? Is there a way?

```
var outer = {
    value: "1",
    inner: {
        getValue: function() {
            return value; // undefined
        }
    }
}

alert(outer.inner.getValue()); // fails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to refer to the containing object, as your "inner" object could have an *infinite* number of containing objects. You have to be explicit and give it a reference to the parent object.

```
var outer = { ... };

var inner = {
  parent: outer,
  getValue: function () { return this.parent.value() }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is refer explicitly to outer object's property via it's reference, e.g.:

```
var outer = {
    value: "1",
    inner: {
        getValue: function() {
            return outer.value; // 1
        }
    }
}

alert(outer.inner.getValue());
```

However this solution is not so flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this by javascript specifications.
Maybe this way:

```
var outer = {
    value: "1",
    inner: (function(){
        var parent = this;
        return {
            getValue: function() {
                return parent.value;
            }
        }
    }).apply(outer)
}
```